# Sending Executable Java over a Socket

Tags: java, sockets, distributed-computing, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a networking project in Java where I want to send some executable code from Node A to Node B and have Node B return the result of the executed code back to Node A.

The way I went about trying to do this (Which I now know isn't suitable for my use case) was to define an abstract class called Job which had an abstract method run(). It looks something like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class Job implements Serializable {

  public String id;

  public Job(String id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public abstract void run();

}
```

I was then planning to be instantiate children classes from Job, defining the run method and to send the derived class from Node A to Node B using the built in `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` and have simply have Node B call the run() method when it received a job.

However this goes beyond what can be done with a Serialized Object sent though the  `ObjectOutputStream` as Node B would need the exact definition of the class being sent from Node A - which it can't have as each Job will be of a different sub type and will have different definitions of the run() method.

Does anyone know of any other way to do this? A way to send executable code from Node A to Node B and have Node B execute the code?

I know I could probably just create .jars and send them through the OutputStream, and have Node B execute them. But if there is any way I could do this with having a base Job class that I can extend and instantiate from to define different types of Jobs and send those Jobs to Node B?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do exactly this via RMI and the codebase feature.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right - this is not possible. If you use object output streams, the **name** of the concrete class is part of the transferred operation; so you need the class definition on the other side (because the JVM will want to **load** the .class file for the object you transferred). So the .class file needs to exist on both sides.

I don't see any other option than sending .class or .jar files and to use reflection to execute the corresponding code.

EDIT: but using reflection ... does still allow you to build different job classes on node A. It still makes sense to organize your classes in a meaningful way; even when you have to transfer them first and then use reflection to invoke them.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was thinking too, it slightly takes away from what I'm trying to achieve but I can't seem to find any other way to do it... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To add to EJP's answer, what you need is a dynamic networked class loading facility, which must be able to fetch the bytecode of classes that are not in the local classpath of your application.

Yes, the [codebase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) feature of an RMI Server should allow you to do that, provided the location of the jars can be expressed as a URL and you have a server infrastructure (or URL handler) to serve it.

I also know of two open source grid computing frameworks which provide this kind of facility implicitely and transparently for the API users: [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org/doc/v5/index.php?title=Class_loading_in_JPPF) and [GridGain](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Zero+Deployment).

*Disclaimer: I'm the main JPPF developer.*

Comment: The codebase link in the answer actually points to javadoc of `java.util.List`, maybe [codebase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html)?

Comment: yes, thanks for catching this! The link is now fixed